# How to modify a two dimensional array passed to a function?

Tags: arrays, function, swift2, inout

My function is as following

```
func helper(root: TreeNode?, _ result: [[Int]], _ list: [Int], _ sum: Int, _ total: Int) {
    list.append(root!.val)
    if(total + root!.val == sum && root?.left == nil && root?.right == nil) {
        result.append(list)
    }
    if(root?.left != nil && sum < total + root!.val) {
        helper(root!.left, result, list, sum, total + root!.val)
    }
    if (root?.right != nil && sum < total + root!.val) {
        helper(root!.right, result, list, sum, total + root!.val)
    }
}
```

When I tried to modify `list` and `result` it gave me errors
. I've searched that `input` keyword can be used to pass parameters by reference, then it can be modified locally as well as externally, but I couldn't make the syntax correct. How can I make it work? Or there is any better way I can modify them?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the inout keyword in the function signature:

```
func helper(root: TreeNode?, inout _ result: [[Int]], inout _ list: [Int], _ sum: Int, _ total: Int)
```

and make the calls using "&" for example:

```
helper(root!.left, &result, &list, sum, total + root!.val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `inout`, not `input`, as [described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) under the heading *In-Out Parameters*.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I used `inout` but it didn't work.